# When using GridView, which is the best option to bind it to the datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, objectdatasource

I'm relatively new to ASP.net and while learning it I came across different ways people use to bind data to GridView:

1. SqlDataSource
2. ObjectDataSource
3. Binding DataTable to GridView control from the code behind.

Which way is preferred and in what situations?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on requirement. But `ObjectDataSource` and `Binding DataTable to GridView control from the code behind` are better then `SqlDataSource`. when you use linq or MVC then Prefer `ObjectDataSource` and for multi-tier architecture ASP.NET prefer `Binding DataTable to GridView control from the code behind`,
I hope you will get the answer.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I decided to do